# Vim. Некорректное отображение цветовой схемы

Tags: terminal, vim, gnome, vimrc

При использовании тем для Vim, фоновый цвет которых отличатся от фонового цвета терминала происходит это(при скроллинге). Использую gnome-terminal

[image: Слетела тема]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение методом "ТЫКА"
Помогло добавление строки в .vimrc

```
set t_ut=
```